# Do we have the case of using both core data and firebase at the same time?

Tags: ios, firebase, core-data

I'm new to ios development. I want to find better way to manage local data and live data in ios app, therefore, i thought of using core data and firebase. or Is there any better way to handle this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database provides [disk persistence features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities). You can enable by setting `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true`. Please provide more information about your specific use case of Firebase and Core Data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site's concept is to work with specific coding issues or questions about API's etc. While you have a good question, it's a bit off-topic for this site. There is no issue using both CoreData and Firebase but, why? If you need a live, cloud based, event driven database, go with just Firebase - no need for CoreData. In regard to @KeroppiMomo comment. Firebase does provide persistence but the idea is to keep the database working when it is temporarily disconnected - like if the device is going through a tunnel and looses internet. It's not designed for full time offline use.

Comment: Firebase has a monitored GoogleGroup that may be better suited for opened ended questions.